# Excel - Populate a Field in one sheet based on another sheet that will copied into the workbook at a later date

Tags: microsoft-excel

Workbook A contains Sheet A that will be populated by a User A and then sent to User B. (this cannot change)
User B will copy Sheet A from Workbook A and copy/paste that sheet into Workbook B.
At this point is there a way to automatically copy certain Cells from Sheet A (now in Workbook B) to Sheet B in Workbook B?

Comment: Welcome! What about [**INDIRECT() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)? Just create **Ref_text** with the name of your `Sheet A` and the address of the cell to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

In the most simplistic way, use an equal sign and the cell it is referencing.

So, in your target cell in "Workbook B", "Worksheet B", place `=Sheet1A1` (where "sheet1" is the title of "worksheet A" in "Workbook B" and "A1" is the source cell in "Worksheet A").